# Chow test in stata

Tags: stata, linear-regression, panel-data

I have two panel regressions:

```
xtreg A b1 c1 d1, fe vce (robust)
xtreg A b2 c2 d2, fe vce (robust)
```

And I'd like to test if b1=b2, c1=c2 and d1=d2
I couldn't find Chow test among Stata postestimation tests. Seems one has to calculate it manually.
However, the formula of Chow test requires Residual SS, which is not reported after `xtreg` command. Can I use between or within R-sq instead?

I have also considered `testparm`command, but it accounts only coefficients of the last estimation. In my case they are coefficients of `b2, c2, d2`. So, maybe there is an opportunity to specify an equation and compare coefficients from different regressions?

Or is there any other option I haven't considered?

Comment: [This link](http://campus.lakeforest.edu/lemke/econ330/stata/lab5/index.html) and [this link](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/computing-chow-statistic/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be `reg` command, which is clear to me. I'm looking for the same hint for the `xtreg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your models are nested you can analyze them using one regression:

```
xtreg A b1 c1 d1 b2 c2 d2, fe vce (robust)
```

Then you can test the coefficients by doing:

```
testparm b1 c1 d1 b2 c2 d2
```